# Enzyme - how to get an instance of a function from a container, to pass as a prop to a component?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have a container component (`MyContainer`) that has a function that is ordinarily passed as a prop to `MyComponent`:

```
export default class MyContainer extends Component {

    ...
    someFunction(e){
        ...
    }
    ...

    render() {
        return (
            <MyComponent
                someFunction={this.someFunction}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

My tests should ensure that `MyComponent` is receiving this function as a prop - firstly, how do I do this? Secondly, should I (can I) make any checks to ensure that this prop is 1) a function and 2) the specific function '`someFunction`'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is based on calling `someFuction` props of `MyComponent`, THEN, check if `someFunction` method of `MyContainer` is called :

```
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import expect from 'expect';

describe('<MyContainer />', () => {

   it(`renders <MyComponent /> which receives the method "MyContainer::someFunction" as props`, () => {
       const someFunctionMethod = sinon.stub(MyContainer.prototype, 'someFunction').returns(true);
       const wrapper = mount(<MyContainer />);
       const actualSomeFunctionProp = wrapper.find(MyComponent).at(0).props().someFunction;

       expect(actualSomeFunctionProp).toBeA('function');
       actualSomeFunctionProp();
       expect(someFunctionMethod.called).toBeTruthy();
       someFunctionMethod.restore();

   })

})
```

Comment: In MyComponent, the function someFunction is required (as dictated by PropType rules). When I test MyComponent, should I use the exact function from MyContainer (as per your answer)? For example, ```const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent someFunction={actual} />);```

Comment: I update the answer many times.. and this is the last version and i hope to be the robustest  unit-test which checks : 1. has props someFunction ,  2. This props is a function. 3. When you call this function , you checks if `MyContainer.prototype.someFunction` is called

Comment: @JoeTidee: Ok i understand.. the unit test that i proposed described `MyContainer` and its content ...... However, whant you want in your last comment is an integration test that checks integration between MyComponent and MyContainer

Comment: @JoeTidee: I rename some variables in the unit-test.. which makes the case more readable.

Comment: Thanks - would you mind answering the first comment above. Should I be using this actualSomeFunctionProp as a prop when running further shallow render tests on MyComponent?

Comment: Since it is unit-test dedicated to `MyComponent`, No need to integrate with it `MyContainer` unless `MyComponent` is used only inside `MyContainer` which  violates the concept of component [Reusable,...etc]  ,Thus,  you can pass any function : `const anyFn= sinon.spy();const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent someFunction={anyFn} />);`

Comment: Ok, but my app uses Redux, hence why I am creating containers for most of my components (to handle subscription/data fetching). ```MyComponent``` IS only used once -  inside ```MyContainer``` - , so what is the alternative pattern?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jest.fn()` to create a [mock function](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/mock-functions.html) and then [determine if it was been called](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/expect.html#tohavebeencalled)

For example, if clicking a button fires your `someFunction`, you might test it like this:

```
it('calls the someFunction handler when the button is clicked', () => {
  const mockFunction = jest.fn();
  const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent someFunction={mockFunction} />);
  wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
  expect(mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Are you saying that it is simply not necessary to pass the exact function from MyContainer as a prop to MyComponent?

Comment: I may have misunderstood what you're testing, but yes, when testing the MyComponent you can pass in a mock function. If testing from the perspective of MyContainer however, this might not be what you're looking for. I think you'd have to call .instance() on a mount(<MyContainer />) and compare its .someFunction to your wrapper.find('MyComponent').props().someFunction

Comment: My thinking was that I will have to test a button click the fires someFunction inside of MyComponent. So, if I am going to have to simulate this, it should be firing the actual function (?) Perhaps this is more of an integration test, but wither way it would be good to know the best way to approach this.